# Android mock connectivity

Tags: android, mocking

Hi I have `Service` which reads Info about connectivity

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
```

is it possible to mock the result of `cm.getActiveNetworkInfo()` just like it is possible for GPS?